# ec2 instance terminated without completing lifecycle action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I am starting up a bunch of ec2 instances in an autoscaling group with autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING and autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_TERMINATING lifecycle hooks. When I initiate an instance termination using aws management console, the instance gets terminated without waiting for me to complete the lifecycle action https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/complete-lifecycle-action.html

The instance state in autoscaling groups UI shows up as **Terminating:Wait** . The instance state in EC2 Instances UI shows up as **Terminated** . This is preventing me from taking an corrective actions before completing the lifecycle action and actually terminating the instance.

The same does not seem to apply for the case when I reduce the desired instances size in autoscaling group. It seems to go through the proper lifecycle stages when I reduce the desired instance size which in turn causes instance terminations.

Is this how aws asg lifecycle hooks are intended to work? They are pretty much useless for any asg instance terminations triggered outside of changing the desired instance size for the asg.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the lifecycle hooks will be called **when Auto Scaling performs the scale-in/scale-out operation**.

The fact that you are *directly* terminating the instance bypasses Auto Scaling, so it does not have an opportunity to activate the termination hooks. All it sees is that an instance is no longer healthy.

If you wish to terminate a specific instance in an Auto Scaling group, use [`terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/autoscaling/terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group.html). That tells Auto Scaling to terminate the instance and the hooks will be used.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, it was driving me mad!